# Is potential energy a scalar operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, tensor-calculus, covariance

If a scalar operator $\hat{S}$ is defined as an operator that is invariant under rotations, i.e 
$$U^\dagger S U = S,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, U=e^{-i\theta\hat{\mathbf{J}}\cdot{\mathbf{n}}}$$
which is equivalent to $$[J_i,S]=0$$

Then, the potential energy $V(\mathbf{r})$ is not a scalar operator unless $V(\mathbf{r})= V(r), r=|\mathbf{r}|$
which seems to contradict this wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_operator#Scalar_operators) and whole lot of standard textbooks.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I think that since usually potential energy only depends on $r$ they are making this assumption.

Comment: @valerio92, as a follow up, if it is not a scalar (or a vector or a tensor) operator, what is it then?

Comment: I think we can safely say that it is a scalar operator in most physical situations.

Comment: It depends on the interaction responsible for the potential energy.  Sometimes it is a scalar, other times it is not.

Comment: The is just the definition of scalar operator. For example,  a potential $v(x,y,z) = z$ is the $0$th component of a rank $1$ spherical tensor operator. Section 3.11 of Sakurai's *Modern Quantum Mechanics* is a good introduction on this topic.

Comment: This is just Wikipedia being wrong.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/490718/proof-that-rotational-symmetric-potential-operators-are-scalar-operators/490827#490827