# Basis representation of $F(\hat{X}, \hat{P},..)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

Suppose I know the position or momentum basis representation $X$ of some operator $\hat{X}$ acting on the ket space. Likewise of $\hat{P}, \hat{A}, \hat{B}, ...$

Is the basis representation of $F(\hat{X}, \hat{P}, \hat{A}, \hat{B},..)$ just   $F(X, P, A, B,..)$?

Comment: Things get complicated due to operator ordering

Comment: Still I see it commonly used in a lot of QM exercises.. maybe it works just fine with products of operators ?

Comment: It works fine as long as you can split F into a function of x and a function of p. Otherwise you'll have to rely on clues such as hermitianness or symmetries

Comment: Provide a simple example of what confuses you.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Take for example I know the momentum basis representation $X=x$ and $P=-ih\partial_x$ and I show $[X,P]=ih$. Does this hold true for the operators $\hat{P}$ and $\hat{X}$ on the ket space itself as well? I know it does, but can I generally switch into an arbitrary basis, I think not.

Comment: In one of my other questions https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/490718/proof-that-rotational-symmetric-potential-operators-are-scalar-operators it worked and this got me wondering.

Comment: Why do you "think not"? Think of these operators as matrices, and basis changes, etc... What spooks you?

Comment: The dimension of the hilbert space does. In for example spin-space I do just that and everything is fine, everything makes perfect sense, the math is easy. In the infinitedimensional hilbert space of position and momentum I'm very much lost though, everything I know about linear algebra seems to break down here. Well, maybe a future course in spectral theory will help.

Comment: You put no emphasis on that in the question. Things work out pretty nicely, but if you want the fussing taken care of, skim the Reed & Simon book. There are, of course, [surpises](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/63/12/201), but these are the exceptions (curiosities)  that prove the rule.